# In a JQuery animation loop, run function after all animations have finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-animate

I have a loop that animates 16 different elements, by getting values as an array. That part works, and it currently animates properly.

I want to call a function after every single animation is done.

```
//loop through the grid
    for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {

            //if its not an empty space
            if (grid[y][x].type != 0) {

                $('#ent'+grid[y][x].entNum).animate({
                    left: (x*16*zoom)+'px',
                    top: ((1+(+y))*16*zoom)+'px'
                },{duration: 100,queue:false,complete:function(){ //end of animation
                    //doesn't really work here
                    okayToMove = true;
                }});

            }
        }
    }
```

You can see that I want to set okayToMove = true after the animation is finished, but as I currently have it, it will set that variable 16 times, and it will be true after the first one is finished, rather than the last one.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a counter for the number of animations

```
var animations = 0;
for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {

        //if its not an empty space
        if (grid[y][x].type != 0) {

            animations++;
            $('#ent'+grid[y][x].entNum).animate({
                left: (x*16*zoom)+'px',
                top: ((1+(+y))*16*zoom)+'px'
            },{duration: 100,queue:false,complete:function(){ //end of animation
                //doesn't really work here
                animations--;
            }});

        }
    }
}
```

Every time an animations starts, the counter is incremented and in the callback of each animation, the counter is decremented. This way as soon as the first animation started, you can monitor the value of the counter and when it reaches 0 again, you know the last animation is finished.

Comment: If you will use the counter? are going to poll the number in the counter and do something only when the counter reaches the interesting value? are you going to use a while loop for it? This is not going to work, $.Deferred was designed exactly for this types of scenario.

Comment: I'm not saying it would work if the counter is polled within a while loop. That'd block the script. I just wanted to provide a non-jQuery solution. The counter can be polled with setTimeout() for e.g. which is pretty much what deferred does to detach from the main execution thread.

Comment: Nope deferred does not use setTimeout. You can write a simple js object that will do the same thing as deferred,  but why bother when there is already one in jquery. In here nothing really detaches from the main execution thread as far as I understand of course :)

Comment: I don't think a while loop would be necessary, if I add an if statement in the animation completed function, that only executes on 0, it should take care of it, yes?

Comment: That's correct, you can check for the value of the counter in each callback and only do your stuff when it's zero. Note, that the solution with jQuery.Deferred is a great one. I just like to come up with pure independent JS solutions and sometimes jQuery is not an options...

Comment: @MarcellFülöp, I looked at it again and I think you are right, for this particular case it might be easy to just execute when your counter reaches certain value right in the loop. Though still has a bad smell for me:) but it is easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using jQuery **$.Deferred**

```
var deferreds = [];


//loop through the grid
    for (var y = 0; y < grid.length; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < grid[y].length; x++) {

            //if its not an empty space
            if (grid[y][x].type != 0) {
                var def = new $.Deferred();    
                deferreds.push(def);
                (function(defferdToResolve){
                   $('#ent'+grid[y][x].entNum).animate({
                    left: (x*16*zoom)+'px',
                    top: ((1+(+y))*16*zoom)+'px'
                    },{duration: 100,queue:false,complete:function(){ //end of animation
                    //doesn't really work here
                    defferdToResolve.resolve();
                    }});
                })(def);


            }
        }
    }
```

This will be the handler for when all of the promises are resolved (i.e. all animations invoked the call back).

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function(){
  alert('All animations are done at this point!');
});
```

To illustrate $.Deferred better here is the [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jtuFi)